# How to keep current $_POST while user logs with facebook ?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have a page which already has S_POST data generated. User is on stage either to register or login with Facebook. If he decides to login with facebook, after successful login he is returned on the same page, but S_POST is an empty array.. 
How to keep current $_POST while user logs with facebook ? I am using Facebook SDK

Comment: Put the data into the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get it right, You have some data already in your $_POST global and if the user tries to login or register using facebook you need to keep the $_POST data and auth token from facebook,

You can any of the following,

1. Print the $_POST to some javascript variable

   var post_data = <?php json_encode($_POST); ?>
2. Now that you have this javascript variable, you can store the data in localstorage and retrieve it later when user is redirected from fb page

Another thing that you can do is store $_POST in cookies at the backend itself, but cookies are to be transferred at every request so if there will be lots of data in $_POST, then the speed will be slower.